# Implementing this Abstract Class using a declaration

Tags: c++, class, interface, abstract

I'm implementing the Automatak [opendnp3](https://www.automatak.com/opendnp3/) libraries for c++. I want to add a [Master to a Channel](https://www.automatak.com/opendnp3/docs/cpp/current/dd/d06/classasiodnp3_1_1_i_channel_a9264ffd76b00a95b2dd0639964624cb4.html#a9264ffd76b00a95b2dd0639964624cb4).As you can see from this definition, a parameter for this action is:

```
...
opendnp3::IMasterApplication& appliction,
...
```

The IMasterApplication interface is described [here](https://www.automatak.com/opendnp3/docs/cpp/current/d5/d64/classopendnp3_1_1_i_master_application.html). So I create masterApplication.cpp and masterApplication.h files and attempt to implement the class as follows:

masterApplication.cpp

```
 #include "masterApplication.h"

 #include <opendnp3/master/IMasterApplication.h>

 #include <iostream>
 #include <chrono>

 using namespace opendnp3;
 using namespace asiodnp3;
 using namespace std;

 masterApplication::masterApplication() {
    }

 masterApplication::~masterApplication() {
    }
```

masterApplication.h

```
#ifndef MASTERAPPLICATION_H_
#define MASTERAPPLICATION_H_

 #include <opendnp3/master/IMasterApplication.h>
 #include <opendnp3/link/ILinkListener.h>
 #include <openpal/executor/IUTCTimeSource.h>

 class masterApplication : public opendnp3::IMasterApplication
 {
 private:

 public:
    masterApplication();
    virtual ~masterApplication();
 };

 #endif
```

But, when I try to declare a masterApplication object in my main to use:

```
masterApplication iMaster;
```

And then place that within the *AddMaster* function, I get the error:

```
main.cpp:57:20: error: cannot declare variable ‘iMaster’ to be of abstract type ‘masterApplication’
   masterApplication iMaster;
```

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Did you implement all the pure virtual methods declared in `IMasterApplication` in class `masterApplication` ?

Comment: No I didn't, is that required? I didn't declare anything but the constructor and destructor.

Comment: Yes it is. Otherwise `masterApplication` remains as abstract.

Comment: So does the declaration of a method make it non-abstract? Also, do I just have to declare it in masterApplication without actually using it?

Comment: Only pure virtual functions are required to be implemented in the base class in order to make it non-abstract if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @DeepBlackDwarf Corrected :)
But in this case the base class is an interface, which usually means all the methods are pure virtual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, whenever implementing an abstract class (interface), all the pure virtual methods that are part of the abstract class must be defined (provided with a body) in the derived class. Then only the derived class becomes concrete, and can be used as a type. Otherwise it also becomes abstract.

"So does the declaration of a method make it non-abstract?"

Not the declaration, but the *definition*. Methods are already declared (as pure virtual) in the base class (interface). Giving them definition (body) in the derived class makes the derived class non-abstract (concrete).

"Also, do I just have to declare it in masterApplication without actually using it? "

You need to *define* all the pure virtual methods of the base class in the derived class. Use them or not will depend on your use-case.

Answer (score 3):

To complete [HappyCoder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32865742/3854322):

Taking a look at the [`opendnp3::IMasterApplication`](https://www.automatak.com/opendnp3/docs/cpp/current/d5/d64/classopendnp3_1_1_i_master_application.html), you can see that it inherits from both `opendnp3::ILinkListener` and `opendnp3::IUTCTimeSource`.

While the first doesn't have any pure virtual method, here is the code of the second ([source](https://www.automatak.com/opendnp3/docs/cpp/current/df/da6/_i_u_t_c_time_source_8h_source.html)):

```
class IUTCTimeSource
{

public:
    virtual UTCTimestamp Now() = 0;
};
```

Then you need to overload the function `Now()` in your class `masterApplication` in order to make it non-abstract.

Comment: Thanks. This really helped me a lot. So if a function is ever pure virtual, you have to overload it and give it a meaning in your function?

Comment: Yes, pure virtual means "I have to be implemented in the derived classes". If you don't, the derived class is also abstract. If you don't want to use it in your derived class (which may be a symptom of a wrong design btw), you can just make a trivial definition for it, like `{return 0;}` or anything that matches its signature